# Azure VNET with subnet segmentation for CosmosDB access

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, subnet, vnet, azure-private-link

Is it possible to have a single VNET with subnets segmentation and allow only some FunctionApps (in subnet "A") to access CosmosDB via Private Link while blocking DB access to other FunctionApps (in subnet "B") on a different subnet?

eg:

VNET:

- default subnet => private link to CosmosDB
- subnet A => FunctionApps that need to connect to CosmosDB through Private Link
- subnet B => FunctionApps that don't need to connect to CosmosDB

I've already implemented the first scenaro with FunctionApps in subnet A connecting to CosmosDB through Private Link on Default subnet.

Now I need to block (for security reasons) other FunctionApps on subnet "B" if it's possibile.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Network Security Group (NSG) and add that to your default subnet to disable any traffic that's not coming from Subnet A.

You can start off with the default ruleset, which allows all traffic within the Virtual Network using the rule `AllowVnetInBound`. Then create a similar rule with a higher priority that does the same, but with the action 'Deny'. That'll disable all traffic within the vnet to the default subnet.

You can then make a rule specifically for subnet A using its IP range to only allow traffic from Subnet A to reach the default subnet.

[image: Example]

Likewise you could do the same but deny outgoing traffic for subnet B, if that would make more sense for your use case.